# (Raspberry Pi - Model 3 B+) Getting wrong values when reading from serial ports ttyS0 or ttyAMA

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, uart

I have a python code that I am using to read from the serial ports '**ttyS0**' or '**ttyAMA0**' at a baudrate of 1.5Mbps.

In my code I basicaly read from the **uart buffer**, convert the bytes I get to hexadecimal, save the reading output into a list, and whenever I reach 10000 elements on the list, I print the result.

After that I check it manually to see if everything is correct.

```
import serial
import time

def getUART():
    # baudrateDaRede = 1507500
    baudrateDaRede = 1500000
    # tty = "ttyAMA0"
    tty = "ttyS0"
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port='/dev/'+tty
    ser.baudrate=1234
    ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
    ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    ser.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    ser.timeout=0.1
    ser.open()
    ser.close()

    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port='/dev/'+tty
    ser.baudrate=baudrateDaRede
    ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
    ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    ser.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    ser.timeout=None
    ser.exclusive = True
    ser.open()
    time.sleep(2)
    index = 0
    vet = []
    while True:
        # time.sleep(0.01)
        if ser.inWaiting() == 0:
                continue
        uartRead = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        uartReadhex = uartRead.hex()
        if not index < 200:
            vet.append(uartReadhex)

        if len(vet) > 10000:
            uartHexa = "".join(vet)
            print(uartHexa)
            vet.clear()
            break
        index += 1

getUART()
```

However, while checking the result sometimes a part of it is missing some **0's** or has more **0's** than it should

**Example**: When reading the output, a part of it should be:

(hex) **6807076860027d00000000df1668**

However, I am getting this:

(hex) **6807076860027d0000000000df1668**

It happens sporadically, but it is enough to make my software not work as intended, since this hexadecimal is the representation of a packet **(and in this case it would be a broken packet)**.

**PS:** I know for sure that the packet is not really broken, because I have used other hardwares other than raspberry to check it and I get the correct values.

I tried to use **minicom** to read from the port and I got the same problem, so I think that my code is not the issue in here and maybe it has something to do with the raspberry itself.

I am runing the code at a **Raspberry Pi - Model 3 B+** using **Raspbian(2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch)**.

I overclocked  it a little, so I am posting below the configuration file of my rapsbian:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
arm_freq=1200
enable_uart=1
force_turbo=1
core_freq=425
gpu_freq=425

#test to over clock ttyAMA0

#init_uart_clock=96000000
#init_uart_baud=1500000
# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi
#dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
```

Comment: What value you have for `init_uart_clock` in `/boot/config.txt`. Have you disable kernel debug messages over UART?

Comment: It depends a lot on your particular setup, versions and all but it is likely that your port is not really running at the baud rate you are asking it. What device are you trying to communicate with? If you have another hardware/software that work you might want to find out how the port is set up there, drivers and other details and try to replicate those.